# UITableView didSelectRowAt cannot proceed to the next view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I got a code from a tutorial from YouTube, download it, and try to use that tutorial app for myself. The Cell Action on his app works so I try to put it on my project. However, once I click the cell, it cannot proceed to the next view controller which I expected to happen since I already have a tutorial for me to copy it and paste on my app. Please help me how will I proceed to the next view controller using these code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TransactionDetails") as! TransactionDetails
       vc.loanNoString = loanNoArray[indexPath.row]
       vc.borrNoString = borrNoArray[indexPath.row]
       vc.loanAmtString = loanAmtArray[indexPath.row]

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a message in console? Is the method called? Is `self.navigationController` nil? Do you have at all a `UINavigationController` on that `UIViewController`?

Comment: Do you have an identifier for the segue? Or it's downloaded from the storyboard? I mean the TransactionDetails

Comment: let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TransactionDetails") as! TransactionDetails Try this code

Comment: @Mannopson , i tried your code but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: @mannopson i do have an identifier for the segue, i named it "TransactionDetails"

Comment: The code looks ok.. Is the delegate set for tableView? put a breakpoint and check if this method is getting called. 

Also check it the navigationController is not nil.

Comment: @Larme, i don't see any message in my console, self.navigationController is not nil. i have a UINavigationController on my uiVC

Comment: @dRAGONAIR yes sir it is, however i just put a while ago the "UITableViewDelegate" but then nothing happens.

Comment: Adding "UITableViewDelegate" is just confirming to the protocol. Have you added the code "tableview.delegate = self" ??

Comment: @dRAGONAIR, not yet... i'll go ahead and put that one. i'm going to that in viewDidLoad, right?

Comment: So this is the source of your issue. 
Also this is very basic thing to do for UITableView. please go through some tutorials. The same thing goes for tableView.dataSource.

Comment: @dRAGONAIR i still can't proceed to the next VC

Comment: you need to add `tableView.delegate = self` in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if you don't have a Navigation Controller.

```
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: i just add it up and make my problem solved!! thanks man!! i really appreciate it. And also for those who gave their suggestions and comments here in my question. really helps a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

I guess it has 3 reason that make your code didn't run correctly:
  1. Did you assign table view delegate to your view controller?
  2. Did you enable User Interaction Interface?
  3. Did you allocate your navigation controller?

Comment: how can i be able to do that?? (newbie here)

Comment: i already assign the table view delegate to my VC, the UI interface is enabled by default. i don't know or get how will i allocate my navigation controller

Comment: is that the that i need to make a "push/present modally" something like that? if that's the case then it's a yes.